# Prove that if $A$ is a countable infinite set, then $A^n$ is also countable infinite

Tags: induction, solution-verification

Prove that if $A$ is a countable infinite set, then each Cartesian product $A^n$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ is also countable infinite.

The book I'm currently using already proved that:

Theorem 1: If $A$ and $B$ are countable infinite sets, then the Cartesian product $A \times B$ is also countable infinite.

So I can use this for proving that $A^n$ is countable infinite.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: $A^2 = A \times A$

Comment: @lulu I will edit my question and give my shot to proof this with induction. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @lulu please see my updated answer.

Comment: Looks good!  $\quad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147873/winther) and especially [fleablood](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/280126/fleablood), I finally proved this with induction.

**Proof**

Basic step: $A^1 = A$ which is countable infinite as it is trivial.

Induction step: We assume that $A^k$ is countable infinite, so we need to prove that $A^{k+1}$ is countable infinite.

We know that

$$A^{k+1} = \underbrace{A \times A \times ... \times A}_\text{$k+1$ times}$$
which is equal to 
$$A^{k+1} = \underbrace{(A \times A \times ... \times A)}_\text{$k$ times} \times A \text{ as } A^{k+1} = A^k \times A$$

By theorem 1 above and the induction step we can say that $A^{k+1}$ is also countable infinite. Therefore, we can say that $A^n$ is countable infinite.